# Need sample JavaScript to query MySQL and display result upon combo box update

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, combobox

I have a combo box that will be loaded with a list of choices.  When the user selects a choice, I need a JavaScript to simply run a query of MySql (obviously based on the user choice in the combo box) which will return a simple, discrete value that then needs to be displayed on the page next to the combo box.

The query is nothing more than `SELECT foo FROM tblexample WHERE id = blah`  (where blah is the combo box value).  The value will be a simple number.  If the user chooses a new value, then it should just re-query and display the result.

I'm open to reading the whole table in upon page load into an array or something too.  I work in PHP but I don't know Javascript; I was only hoping for a sample code bit; I can read and extrapolate most of the time.

I just didn't want to put a submit button in a form and force the user to do that each time they look at a new combo box choice. I wanted a more seamless, quick display for them.

Comment: Are you looking for Java help (the serverside language that gets complied) or javascript (the scripting language that runs in your browser and is useful for ui handling)? I think you may be confusing the two languages together- getting that straightened out will probably give you more useful responses.

Comment: Are you working with JSP/Servlet (web application)?

Comment: Javascript is apparently what I'm looking for.  Thanks, as said, I'm very experienced in PHP, not so much in java(script).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language. It will not run MySQL queries (safely, at least). Use PHP to dynamically create the HTML and JavaScript for the combo box.

PHP has an [entire section of their documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) reserved for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I can code the PHP version of this in my sleep; I've done it that way plenty of times.  I had wanted to do it without having to submit the page and wait for the refresh so the user could just see the results appear as they try different values for the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually looking for a reference in Ajax programming using PHP on the backend and javascript on the front end.

My recommendation would be to look at using one of the excellent Javascript development frameworks. Great candidates would be JQuery or Prototype. They both give you solid libraries to simplify programming in javascript.

Rather than working with sample code, you'll probably get a lot further by developing javascript expertise. Ajax is complicated, and you'll need to at least get basic skills together before you can start to integrate javascript and PHP.

Here's a good query to get started- I'd recommend beginning with JQuery if you have to pick one.

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ajax+php+jquery+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Once you get started on jQuery as Tim mentioned you could do this,

The select box,

```
<form name="formName" action="" method="">
  <select name="selName">
   <option value={uniqueId}>Option 1</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p class="displayMsg">No message to display.... yet</p>
```

The javascript and jQuery in a script tag of the head tag,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select[name=selName]').change(function() {
  function processData(data, success) {
   ...do something with the query results echoed into var data...such as
   $('p.displayMsg').txt(data); // which will update the text node of the p tag class displayMsg
  } // end function processData
  var formData = $('form[name=formName]').serialize(); // this will encode the variables from the form to pass into post headers. You can access in your ajax called script with $_POST['selName']
  $.post('phpAjaxProcessScript.php',formData,processDataClose); // sends data to script and when it's done it calls function processData
 }); // end select change event function call
}); // end document ready event function call
```